# UITextView, Distance between order number with title and content - Swift

Tags: swift, uitextview

Example, i have a string like this:

"1. Title One.\n1.1. This is line one of content one...This is line two.\n2. Title Two.\nThis is content of title two."

When i show in UITextView like this:

[image]

but i want to show it in UITextView like this:

[image]

How i can do it?

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing exactly?

Comment: i've edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\t` after every new line `\n`

"1.\tTitle One.\n1.1.\tThis is line one of content one...This is line two.\n2.\tTitle Two.\n\tThis is content of title two."

Comment: I just want to be sure, are you getting the data from server or this is local string?

Comment: it's local string, but so long

Comment: The thing you want  is not possible with this response, You need to customise the control. Because you cannot add `\t` everywhere needed in the response from server. What you can do is get the string and paragraph indicator like 1.1, 2.1.1 in other keys, and customise the control

Answer (score 0):

Use an attributed string. It's rather verbose though:

```
let indent: CGFloat = 36.0

let bodyParagraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
bodyParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = indent
bodyParagraphStyle.headIndent = indent

let headerParagraphStyle = bodyParagraphStyle.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableParagraphStyle
headerParagraphStyle.firstLineHeadIndent = 0
headerParagraphStyle.tabStops = [NSTextTab(textAlignment: .Left, location: indent, options: [:])]

let bodyAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: bodyParagraphStyle]
let headerAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: headerParagraphStyle]

let text = NSMutableAttributedString()
text.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "1\tTitle 1\n", attributes: headerAttributes))
text.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "1.1\tThis is line one of content one\n", attributes: headerAttributes))
text.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "This is line two\n", attributes: bodyAttributes))
text.appendAttributedString(NSAttributedString(string: "This is line three\n", attributes: bodyAttributes))

self.textView.attributedText = text
```